# Orientation of permutated basis/change of sign

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $V$ be a real $n$-dimensional oriented vector space. Let $(v_1,...,v_n)$ be a basis and let $O(v_1,...,v_n)\in\{-1,+1\}$ be its orientation: $+1$ $(-1)$ if the basis is positively (negatively) oriented.

My guess would be that the following two equations are true:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
O\left(v_{\sigma(1)},...,v_{\sigma(n)}\right)=\text{sgn}(\sigma)O(v_1,...,v_n)
\end{equation}
for some permutation $\sigma\colon\{1,...,n\}\to\{1,...,n\}$ and
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
O\left((-1)^{k_1}{v_1},...,(-1)^{k_n}{v_n}\right)=(-1)^{k_1+\ldots+k_n}O(v_1,...,v_n)
\end{equation}
for $(k_1,...,k_n)\in\mathbb{N_0}^n$.

**Question:** Are the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ correct? Can I find them somewhere?

**My considerations:**

1. First elementary result:
   \begin{equation}
   O(v_1,...,v_i,...,v_j,...,v_n)=-O(v_1,...,v_j,...,v_i,...,v_n),
   \end{equation}
   Explanation: We obtain the transformation matrix by multiplying the identity matrix with a permutation matrix that swaps to rows or two columns - an [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-switching_transformations) with determinant $-1$ - and the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants.
2. Second elementary result:
   \begin{equation}\tag{2}
   O(v_1,...,-v_i,...,v_n)=-O(v_1,...,v_i,...,v_n)
   \end{equation}
   Explanation: The transition matrix is the identity, expcept that one entry is $1$ instead of $-1$ and the determinant of a diagonal matrix is simply the product of the numbers on the diagonal.
3. I'd say that we can now prove the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ by induction.

**Further comment:** I know that an orientation is often defined to be an equivalence class $O\subset V^n$ ($O$ is the set of all positively oriented bases and $B\setminus O$ is the set of all negatively oriented bases). Let $B\subset V^n$ be the set of all ordered bases and let $[x]$ be the equivalence class of $x\in B$. The map
\begin{align}
O\colon B&\to\{-1,1\}\\
x&\mapsto O(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }[x]\in O\\-1&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}
I used above then assigns the number $1$ to positively oriented bases and $-1$ to negatively oriented bases.

Comment: Yes, they are correct, and depending on exactly how you define an orientation (a connected component of $\bigwedge^n V^n\setminus \{0\}$, the $n$th wedge product of $V^n$ less the origin, is a favorite of mine), your argument is one of the easiest ways of seeing it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Alright, thank you for the confirmation :)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Just of curiosity: Why is that your favourite definition? It seems very abstract and more complicated

Comment: It doesn't require bases or determinants to define (at least not directly - proving that it is well-defined effectively requires a basis). And "more complicated" is subjective. It requires some time to build up the concept of the wedge product, but once that is a accomplished, you then have a tool useful in a variety of situations, making them overall much less complicated than the alternatives.